# What is the correct URL to call a phone number from iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift

Using following code to call a  phone number:

```
let number : String = "1860-425-0000"

 if  let url : URL = URL(string: "tel://\(number)"){ 
     UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
  }
```

Result is:

[image]

Problem is, while calling ,it is appending a  different country's code in place of the correct country code.

How can I make it 18604250000 instead of +1(860) 425-0000 ?

Comment: What country code are you trying to have it call? And the problem might also be related to the country the device is set to. It is trying to dial a US/Canada telephone the device might be set to a country that uses one of those formats for their phone number. Check Settings->General->Language and Region to determine the country the device is set to. Again this is just a shot in the dark but iOS does use the device region to determine proper phone number formats and country codes.

Answer (score 1):

For making call with a popup

```
if let url = URL(string: "telprompt://\(number)") {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            }
```

swift 3.0

```
guard let number = URL(string: "telprompt://" + number) else { return }
UIApplication.shared.open(number)
```

For direct call without a popup

```
if let url = URL(string: "tel://\(number)") {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            }
```

Swift 3.0

```
UIApplication.shared.open(number, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: this method will remove 0 from the first of the number

Comment: Just to add to this, I added some spaces to the number and then it does nothing, so just makes your your phone number is a continuous string of numbers (maybe with a + at the beginning).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just separate each section with hyphens. i.e

```
let number: String = "tel://1-860-425-0000"
```

Check out the Apple Docs about it. [Phone Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html)

The other thing to look at is if it is not recognizing the first section as the country code you should be able to prefix the number with the + sign.

```
let number: String = "tel://+1-860-425-0000"
```

Answer (score -2):

A Swift 3 Code:

```
func makeCall(mobileNumber:String) {

  if let mobileCallUrl = URL(string: "tel://\(mobileNumber)") {

    let application = UIApplication.shared
    if application.canOpenURL(mobileCallUrl) {
        application.open(mobileCallUrl, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
  }
}
```

You should be able to use makeCall("1860-425-0000") to make a call.